# Hashcat : Separator unmatched

Tags: hash, sha, separator, sha512, hashcat

I'm trying to crack a SHA-512 hash file. The format of the message is Format - $6$Salt$Password.

I'm using Hashcat for the same.
I'm getting the error : Separator Unmatched.

Below is my command :
Hashcat -a 0 -m 1720 filename.txt /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt

I'm getting the error :
Hashfile on line1 ( content ) : Separator unmatched.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The format for `-m 1720` is `976b451818634a1e2acba682da3fd6efa72adf8a7a08d7939550c244b237c72c7d42367544e826c0c83fe5c02f97c0373b6b1386cc794bf0d21d2df01bb9c08a:2613516180127` as shown [here](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes)

You probably want to use `-m 1800`.